# PHP: DomElement->getAttribute

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

How can I take all the attribute of an element? Like on my example below I can only get one at a time, I want to pull out all of the anchor tag's attribute.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML(http://www.example.com);

$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
echo $a->getAttribute('href');
```

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Inspired" by Simon's answer. I think you can cut out the `getAttribute` call, so here's a solution without it:

```
$attrs = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $a->attributes->length; ++$i) {
  $node = $a->attributes->item($i);
  $attrs[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
}
var_dump($attrs);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$length = $a->attributes->length;
$attrs = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
    $name = $a->attributes->item($i)->name;
    $value = $a->getAttribute($name);

    $attrs[$name] = $value;
}


print_r($attrs);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach($a as $element)
{
   echo $element->getAttribute('href');
}
```

Comment: If I read the question right, he wants all the element's attributes.

Not one attrbiute from all elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$html = $data['html'];
if(!empty($html)){
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTML($html);
   $doc->saveHTML();
   $datadom = $doc->getElementsByTagName("input");
   foreach($datadom as $element)
   {
       $class =$class." ".$element->getAttribute('class');
   }
}
```