# Using php, how can I save an attribute value of a paragraph tag?

Tags: php, jquery, attributes

I have a page where I can move a paragraph tag using jQuery UI draggable. Whenever I move the paragraph tag, the inline style for that tag is changed as so:

```
position: relative; left: 280px; top: 300px;
```

I have a form directly beneath that. When I submit the form, I want the php to save those two attribute values(top & left).

How can I save the multiple attribute values of the paragraph tag?

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327429/php-domelement-getattribute) answer, but I don't understand where the $attrs array comes from or what's in it. Maybe that's what I'm missing?

Comment: I would suggest to use Paul Dixon's answer , but just for make it clear, $attrs are coming from $a = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a"); which you may find in your attached question. 
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) jQuery event handler, so that just before the form is sent, you read the position of the paragraph and store it in a hidden form field.

Another way would be to update some hidden form fields whenever the user changes the paragraph position.

(Edit: the answer you reference is about dealing with an HTML DOM on the *server* side, whereas this question is really about the *client* side. This is more a Javascript question than a PHP one)

Answer (score 1):

I use a hidden  tag for an application which saves the position of several DOM elements. Just remember to check their values when you receive them in your PHP script.

$('#element').css('top') and .css('left') will give you their values.
Edit:
Alternatively you can use position to get their values either through .position() or .offset()

```
position = $('#element').position();
// or
position = $('#element').offset();
// position.left and position.top
```

Which one you should choose [depends on how the element is positioned.](http://circuitbomb.com/index.php/2009/10/jquery-offset-and-position/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly from PHP. PHP doesn't know anything that happens in the browser unless the browser sends that information to the script.

You'll need to send the `top` and `left` values manually. The best way is to listen for the submit event:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var position = $('#yourP').position();

    $('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'left', value: position.left}).appendTo(this);
    $('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'top', value: position.top}).appendTo(this);

    this.submit(); // submit the form with the extra values
});
```

You can then access these values with `$_POST['top']` and `$_POST['left']` (or the GET equivalents if your form uses `GET`) in your PHP script.

Comment: I tried your approach and the form is not submitting now. I also tried switching out the $('<input/>', for $('input', to see if that was the problem, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. Somehow 'this.submit();' is not making it submit the form as it should.